# Url Download link image Can't be view in xcode

Tags: xcode

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize NetImage;

@implementation PlayGameViewController
- (IBAction)imageView:(id)sender {
       //Content of image should be received. But it not show on ImageView.
        NSLog(@"\n Image == %@ ",[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.so.cityhi.com/cometchat/plugins/filetransfer/download.php?file=559192_10152684963740198_1083006183_n.jpg"]]);

        // NetImage is image View.
        NetImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.so.cityhi.com/cometchat/plugins/filetransfer/download.php?file=559192_10152684963740198_1083006183_n.jpg"]]];
        //It working good

        //NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://so.cityhi.com/public/user/52/0052_37ea.png"]];
        //[NetImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
        NSLog(@"Success");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply If we want to use Image with URL.here is simply code and as you did is good.

```
NSString *ImageURL = @"YourURLHere";
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
//imageView is Your UIImageView That you created in your .h file with IBOutlet
```

But when i use your given Image url (http://www.so.cityhi.com/cometchat/plugins/filetransfer/download.php?file=559192_10152684963740198_1083006183_n.jpg)

and requested on Browser then Image not showing that's why it may an issue with your image try another image as well.